# Screenshot all child elements of element

Tags: python, selenium

I need to take a screenshot of all of the div's and p's within a selected element individually, here's what I have so far:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'www.example.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
i = 0
body= driver.find_element_by_id('body-text')
for element in body:
    i=i+1
    image_title = "pic"+str(i)+".jpg"
    print("saving"+image_title)
    item.screenshot(image_title)
```

What is the proper way to go by each element individually?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for element in body.find_elements_by_xpath(".//p | .//div"):
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
     #insert your code 
     element.screenshot(image_title)
```

To get all divs and p elements regardless of nesting you can do the following.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is very helpful. Us there a way to do this with all nested elements in order? Basically, instead of getting all P elements and then all Div, it selects the first element, then the second, regardless of tag type?

Comment: I think this does in order it should cycle between them.